# Need another riley riddle

Tags: riddle, word

Didn't see a riley riddle in the top five so I guess we needed one.

> My prefix is the way you spell one in texting and/or games.
>
> My infix is the first word of misleading clues backward
>
> My infix 2 is a synonym for being nice
>
> My suffix is the first infix (with overlap with the second infix which is a one letter overlap)

Comment: Don't Riley Riddles usually have a definition of the whole word?

Comment: Since it was so easy I think think about that

Comment: I am working on an anagram puzzle, at the moment. Otherwise I would have done a Riley Riddle :P

Comment: Why the downvote?  What is wrong with this puzzle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's

> Wunderkinder

My prefix is the way you spell one in texting and/or games.

> Wun

My infix is the first word of misleading clues backward

> Der - reverse of red (herring)

My infix 2 is a synonym for being nice

> Kind

My suffix is the first infix (with overlap with the second infix which is a one letter overlap)

> Der

Comment: Yay! Knew it wasn't to hard